# Scaling Random variables by a constant

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

First, let me state the problem:

"Customers at Fred's cafe win a 100 dollar prize if their cash receipts show a star on each of the five consecutive days Monday...Friday in any one week. The cash register is programmed to print stars on a randomly select 10% of the receipts. If Mark eats at Fred's once each day for four consecutive weeks and the appearance of stars is an independent process, what is the standard deviation of $X$, where $X$ is the number of dollars won by Mark in the four-week period"

The probability model that can best solve this would be a Binomial with parameters $n = 4$ and $p = 0.1^5$.

Folks can quickly solve this creating a random variable $Y = 100X$ and just getting the Variance of the binomial and taking the root.

The variance for Binomial is $np(1-p)$ 
$$
\operatorname{Var}[100X] = 100^2 \operatorname{Var}[X].
$$

This method seems significantly more peaceful than finding the second moment and first moment of this new random variable $Y$.

My issue comes from this allowance of multiplying $X$ by $100$ for the expected payout for this particular problem. How is it that we translate this word problem in such a way? When $n = 0$ this $100$ shouldn't be getting multiplied by the probability I thought.

Can someone help me make this jump?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is a binomial, that is it's the sum of $0$ and $1$, $0$ if you don't win and $1$ if you win. But you want to find the variance of the payoff, and in that case you get $0$ if you don't win and $100$ if you win. This is exactly $100X$, so that what you're looking for

Comment: A more apt question, I guess would be for me to ask what exactly does it mean to multiply 100 by the random binomial variable X? If we were to just not use the variance formula, how would we use this 100X to find the Variance?

Comment: @Marco In the usual way; to compute the mean for example you use $$E(Y) = \sum_{y} y P(Y=y) = \sum_{x} 100x P(100x  = 100X) = \sum_x 100 x P(x = X)$$ and so on for the second moment and variance and whatever :)